# If $\sum a_n$ is divergent then $\sum -a_n$ also diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Is the following argument legit? Please note, that by $\sum$, I denote $\sum^\infty_{n=1}$.

**Proposition:** If the series $\sum a_n$ is divergent then the series $\sum -a_n$ also diverges.

**Proof:** Suppose that $\sum{a_n}$ is divergent and assume for contradiction, that $\sum -a_n$ is convergent. Then $ -1 \cdot \sum -a_n = \sum{-1 \cdot -a_n} = \sum a_n $ would also converge. This contradicts our supposition, so $\sum -a_n$ has to be divergent.

Comment: It's ok.  Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: The new sum is $-1$ times the original sum, so they both converge or both diverge. Correct proof.

Comment: Fine. Personally I would structure it as a proof by contrapositive, rather than by contradiction.

Comment: This is correct. Note that the meat of the proof is that $\lim cS_n = c\lim S_n$ for nonzero constant $c$ (here $S_n$ is a partial sum), which may need to be proven if it isn't already in your toolkit. That shows that one sum converges if and only if the other does. Remember, statements about convergence/divergence of "infinite sums" are really statements about limits, not sums.

Comment: @Mateo Pro tip: bump up tiny comments with Mathjax, e.g. `${}{}{}{}$`

Comment: @TheoBendit, this is a nice idea. Thank you.